# Scipy method matching python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, correlation

I want to make this code faster, as it takes ~4 miliseconds for a 1000x1000 image with a window size of 10x10.

```
import numpy
import scipy.misc
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

def corr(a, b):
    '''finds the correlation of 2 intensities'''
    return (sum2(a,b)/(sum2(a,a)*sum2(b,b))**0.5)

def sum2(a,b):
    s = 0
    for x in range(len(a)):
        s += a[x]*b[x]
    return s

##the commented code displays the images     
##plt.ion()
def find_same(img1,img2,startx,width,starty,hight):
    '''inputs 2 filenames, startx, width of search window, and hight.'''     
    crop_img = img1[starty:(starty+hight),startx:(startx+width)]
    plt.imshow(crop_img,interpolation='nearest')
    plt.draw()
    a = []
    for x in numpy.nditer(crop_img): #converting image to array of intesities
        a.append(float(x))     
    mcfinder = []
    for x in range(img2.shape[1]-width):
        finder = img2[starty:(starty+hight),x:(x+width)]
        b = []
        for y in numpy.nditer(finder):
            b.append(float(y))
        correl = corr(a,b) #find correlation
        mcfinder.append(correl)
    maxim = max(mcfinder)
    place = mcfinder.index(maxim)
    finder = img2[starty:(starty+hight),place:(place+width)]
##    plt.imshow(finder,interpolation='nearest')
##    plt.draw()
##    time.sleep(1)
##    plt.close()
    return maxim,place

img1 = scipy.misc.imread('me1.bmp')
img2 = scipy.misc.imread('me2.bmp')
starttime = time.clock()
print find_same(img1,img2,210,40,200,40)
endtime = time.clock()
print endtime-starttime
```

Are there any ways to make this faster? Or am I doing this fundamentally wrong?
Please let me know. To run this you need matplotlib, scipy, and numpy.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that you can speed this up by at least one order of magnitude by writing it fully in numpy and avoiding unnecessary for loops. Since you already have working code, this could be a good candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you decide to post there please check the instructions on how to post at Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

[I lack the reputation to post this as a comment]

As mentioned in @cel's comment, you should vectorize your code by using only numpy operations instead of loops over lists.

It seems you are trying to do some template matching, did you have a look at the [example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_template.html) for `skimage.feature.match_template()` from the scikit-image documentation? scikit-image also provides windowed views (`skimage.util.view-as-windows()`) of a numpy array which is very handy, when you are analyzing a numpy array block-by-block.

If you don't want to add another dependency you should use Scipy's special functions to compute the correlation for you, e.g. `scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate()` (also have a look at the other functions in [scipy.ndimage.filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.filters)).